# Can't connect to remote SQL server in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception, database-connection

I created a database on freesqldatabase.com and was in the process of writing a C# script to connect to it and I cannot seem to get it to connect successfully. I think the issue is in the connection string, but I'm not sure what the problem is. I've been trying to get advice from documentation, but I haven't been able to fix it. My connection method is below:

Note: connAddr = sql3.freesqldatabase.com

Note: port = 3306

```
    public static void Connect(string connAddr, int port)
    {
        CloseConnection();

        Conn = new SqlConnection();

        Conn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=" + connAddr + "," + port + ";" +
            "Initial Catalog=sql332572;" +
            "user id=sql332572;" +
            "pwd=xxxxxxxx";
        Conn.Open();
    }
```

I am getting the below error. Searching Google didn't seem to give me any information on this particular error:

```
Exception: Unknown packet type 91
Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacketHeader ()
Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacket ()
Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetByte ()
```

Can you guys see anything wrong with my connection string? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can u debug and paste what values you get in connAddr and port.

Comment: Initial Catalog should be your database name

Comment: Maybe try using `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` to ctreate your connection string? Aspects of the connection string don't look right?

Comment: @voddy, on the database supplied by this website, the database and usernames are the same. Thanks though.

Comment: @Ozraptor, I am looking into that now... In the meantime, could you let me know which aspects of my original connection string that don't look right? Thanks again

Comment: Assuming your database's name is your username, your connection string looks fine to me. `pwd` is more typical of the SQL Server Native Client than the .NET Data Provider for SQL Server (with which `Password` is more typical), but it should work. Given the error message you get, be sure to double check your port #. ConnectionStrings.com has a good overview of [SQL Server connection strings by provider/driver](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format for your connection string:

```
Server=;Database=;uid=;pwd=;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.freesqldatabase.com/mssql/

they will launch MS SQL Server connection soon, i.e. they don't provide it now. What are you trying to connect to? If it is MySql than Sqlconnection would not work.